# Enviar dados no formato json para o php

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json

Sei que é totalmente viável o envio de json do PHP para JS, mas é possível o envio dos meu dados via ajax no formato json para o PHP?

Comment: Sim é possível.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sim, é possível o envio de dados via ajax no formato json para o PHP.

A intenção do formato JSON é ser universal. Apesar do formato JSON ser sintaxe JavaScript, ele é lido por outras linguagens e é hoje o padrão para enviar dados.

### Do JavaScript para PHP:

```
var json = JSON.stringify(dados);
```

e no PHP:

```
$dados = json_decode($json);
```

### Do PHP para JavaScript

```
$json = json_encode($dados);
```

e no JavaScript:

```
var dados = JSON.parse(json);
```

#### Mais leitura:

- [JSON na WikiPedia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON)
- [A tag JSON aqui no SOpt](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/json/info)
- [JSON é igual a um array Associativo?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/41143/129)

Comment: Obrigado, me ajudou muito.

Comment: Mas como envio o json para php?

Comment: @Neo dá uma olhada aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/20920/129